# Calculate percentage value for each row based on total column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below. I need to calculate percentage value for each row based on total column value. How to achieve this with a SQL query?

[image]

I am expecting results like this:

[image]

Please find the below simple calculation to get result.

```
(100 / 1000) * 100 = 10
```

for the first value.

```
(row value / grand total) * 100
```

Can you please help me to get 10 as result for the first row value with a SQL query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to join the total cost value. Then consume this value to calculate the percentage, like: `... CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(cost) FROM mytable) AS t`

Comment: Be **careful**: `100 / 1000` in T-SQL is an **integer** division and will result in a value of **0**. You need to use **decimal** values to get fractional results, e.g. `100.0 / 1000.0` .....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `SUM()` function as analytic function over the entire table to compute the total sum.  Then, just divide each region's cost by that sum to obtain the percentage.

```
SELECT
    Region,
    Cost,
    100 * Cost / SUM(Cost) OVER () AS Percentage
FROM yourTable
```

Note that you *could* have also used a non correlated subquery to find the total cost, e.g.

```
(SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM yourTable)
```

But the first version I gave you might outperform if for no other reason than it requires running only a single query.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

**Update:**

For your updated query I might use the following:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Region,
        SUM(Cost) AS sum_cost
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Region
)

SELECT
    Region,
    sum_cost,
    100 * sum_cost / SUM(sum_cost) OVER () AS Percentage
FROM cte;
```

## Demo

Comment: The above query works fine. In case if i add group by clause it will throws some exception. 
SELECT
    Region,
    Cost,
    100 * Cost / SUM(Cost) OVER () AS Percentage
FROM yourTable group by Region, Cost

How to achieve this with group by clause.

Comment: Is this what you want? `SELECT Region, SUM(COST) FROM yourTable GROUP BY Region` ?  You can always ask another question.

Comment: Is this what you want? `SELECT Region, SUM(COST) FROM yourTable GROUP BY Region` ?  You can always ask another question.

Comment: The above query works fine for my expectation. In case if my table has redundant region values, how to achieve the same without getting redundant values through the below query. 

SELECT Region, Cost, 100 * Cost / SUM(Cost) OVER () AS Percentage FROM yourTable group by Region.

Comment: Update this question with additional data or just ask a new question.

Comment: I have updated my source and target table. Kindly check this and provide your comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152016/discussion-between-umapathy-s-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 1):

You can get a result with below query.

```
;with Sales(region,cost,Total)
    as
    (
    select region,cost,
    (sum(cost) over()) as Total
    from YourTable
    )
    Select Region,Cost,convert(numeric(18,0),Cost/1000*100) as Per from sales
```